# Set global exception handler from inside a thread (in Django)

Tags: python, django, exception, except

I know about this [python bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue1230540), which does not allow `sys.excepthook` to be used from inside a thread. A recommended workaround is to surround the thread's `run` method with try/except. However, since I am using Django, I am already locked in in Django main thread.

So: Is there any way to globally catch exceptions in Django?

Comment: Have you found a good solution for this problem? It's solvable in flask, but I can't find an error handler for django.

Comment: Not at all, unfortunately. I put it on back burner.